# How is it possible that an annotation can be an annotation to itself?

Tags: java, annotations

I was browsing through the documentation of JDK 7 when I noticed an annotation called `@Target` in package `java.lang.annotation`. The header of that class is

```
@Documented
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Target(value=ANNOTATION_TYPE)
public @interface Target
```

Now, `@Target` is used as an annotation to itself. How is this possible? `@Target` is used in the header even before it is declared. I tried this with annotations I had written, and it worked as well. Can anyone explain what's happening here?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? The compiler probably simply parses the class before parsing its annotations. Note that you can also have self-referencing classes (like a recursive tree of nodes, for example)

Comment: annotations don't do anything, you should not except errors or something new with the process, they are used to much in reflection, for signing a member :)

Answer (score 3):

The JLS specifically anticipates this, in [section 9.6 Annotation Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6):

> If an annotation `a`
>   ([§9.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7))
>   on an annotation type declaration corresponds to an annotation type
>   `T`, and `T` has a (meta-)annotation `m` that corresponds to
>   `java.lang.annotation.Target`, then `m` must have either an element
>   whose value is `java.lang.annotation.ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE`, or
>   an element whose value is `java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE`, or
>   a compile-time error occurs.

No other part of section 9.6 or 9.7 says anything about it being illegal for an annotation declaration to be annotated with a reference to the annotation being declared.